# defining a sequence of numbers L n≥1, and prove something about it

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

So i was given this question just to try for practice to test our knowledge and i'm really confused on how to go about this question. How should i go about this question, i'm confused with the greek notation and also on how to approach it.

In this question, we will define a sequence of numbers $$L_n$$ for $$n \geq 1$$, and prove something about it.  The differences from what you may have seen so far are:
* It has two base cases,
* And the definition of $$L_{n+1}$$ involves both $$L_n$$ and $$L_{n-1}$$.
* You will still do "induction", but you need to check //two// base cases!
** Let $$L_1 = 1, L_2 = 3$$.
** And with $$n \geq 2$$, define $$L_{n+1} = L_n + L_{n-1}$$.
**  Prove that $$L_n = \varphi^n + \Phi^n$$, where $$\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$$ and $$\Phi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$$.
*** //Note: The quantity $$\varphi$$ is referred to as the "golden ratio", and the quantity $$\Phi$$ is related to it. The Greek letters $$\varphi$$ and $$\Phi$$ are both called "phi", but the first is lower-case and the second is upper-case.//
*** //Hint: In order to do this question, you should check that $$\varphi$$ and $$\Phi$$ are the two roots of the equation $$x^2 = x+1$$.  This may help in the inductive step...//

Comment: If the "greek notation" is the only thing confusing you, replace $\varphi$ with $A$, replace $\Phi$ with $B$, and then solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

So $L_n = \phi^n + \Phi^n$ and $L_{n-1} = \phi^{n-1} + \Phi^{n-1}$, and we have
$$
L_{n+1} = L_n + L_{n-1} = \phi^n + \Phi^n + \phi^{n-1} + \Phi^{n-1}
        = \phi^{n-1} (\phi+1) + \Phi^{n-1} (\Phi+1)
$$
and now use the fact that $\phi$ and $\Phi$ solve $x^2 = x+1$, so $\phi+1=\phi^2$ and $\Phi+1 = \Phi^2$.

Can you finish the proof?

Comment: Oh i see but when you said use the fact ϕ and Φ, what fact?

Comment: Where did you use induction?

Comment: @Zero to assume that $L_n$ and $L_{n-1}$ have the desired form, you need strong induction

Comment: @Rohan you the fact that both $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are solutions of $x^2=x+1$

Comment: I don't understand where you used it in your hint.

Comment: @Zero the hint starts off by assuming that $L_n = \phi^n + \Phi^n$ and $L_{n-1} = \phi^{n-1} + \Phi^{n-1}$. This is the Inductive Assumption, and we should prove the statement for $L_{n+1}$...

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @gt6989b can you clarify what you mean by use the fact?

Comment: @Zero note that $\phi$ and $\Phi$ both satisfy $x^2 = x+1$. Can you use this fact to complete the proof?

Comment: Can I say that $\phi$ = $\phi$^2 -1? and similarly for the other letter. Then sub them in?

Comment: @Zero you can, but I don't see how this will help

Comment: I dont see how to finish the proof. i tried subbing in stuff, and everything but can't figure it out.